# How to Fix this Sidebar.php

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

ALEXA bar code is broken, can you help me fix it? IT would be a great help. I think Tag is not closed. That's why my website page's footer is gone.

FUll Code is here: http://ideone.com/hqUTJ3

Preview:

```
<?php
if(tie_get_option( 'columns_num' ) != '2c'):
?>
<aside class="sidebar-narrow">
<?php
    if ( is_home() ){

        $sidebar_home = tie_get_option( 'sidebar_narrow_home' );
        if( $sidebar_home )
            dynamic_sidebar ( sanitize_title( $sidebar_home ) ); 

        else dynamic_sidebar( 'narrow-primary-widget-area' );
```

Comment: You didn't close the first if ?

Comment: This is full code http://ideone.com/hqUTJ3

The one given above is just PREVIEW.

Comment: Do not post code as "preview" especially if you don't warn people first. Update the question with the full code so future readers don't get broken or dead links.

Comment: @Kai Qing - When I add ideone link, it says add code when adding ideone link.

Comment: I don't know what that means, but either way you should update this question and move whatever you posted on that ideone site to this one using the code markup. looks like {} in the editor. You'll notice you have not got much attention on this question. It may have to do with the general rule that we don't typically just click on outbound links in questions. Could be spam.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php
    if (tie_get_option('columns_num') != '2c') :
?>
    <aside class="sidebar-narrow">
<? endif ?> // <-- You need to close your if() : above

<?php
    if (is_home()) {

        $sidebar_home = tie_get_option( 'sidebar_narrow_home' );
        if ($sidebar_home) {
            dynamic_sidebar(sanitize_title($sidebar_home)); 
        }
        else {
            dynamic_sidebar('narrow-primary-widget-area');   
        }
    } // <--- You need to close your if
```

I would recommend not using braceless blocks of code. IE

```
if (true)
    dothis();
```

To help segment your code so this problem doesn't happen again, use braces around every conditional code block. It keeps things organized, readable, formattable and debuggable to the human eye.

```
if (true) {
    dothis();
}
```

Comment: always nice when questions are asked without all the info. *sigh*

Comment: im plussing this cause this would have fixed what OP posted.